# Unable to download zip file in angular 7

Tags: angular, blob, angular7

I am working on an angular 7 application. Backed-end of my application is in .NET Core. I have to download a zip file returned by API in angular. My angular component code is:

```
ExportDataScienceAnalytics()
{
    this.uploadService.exportDataScienceAnalytics(this.selectedAlgorithm).subscribe(data => {
      saveAs(data, "test")
    })
}
```

**exportDataScienceAnalytics** method implementation is:

```
exportDataScienceAnalytics(algoName): Observable<Blob> {
    var abc = Constants.DataScienceUrl + 'exportdatascienceanalytics/' + algoName;
    return this.get(Constants.DataScienceUrl + 'exportdatascienceanalytics/' + algoName, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

Issue is that when i run the code i get the following error in console:

[image]

My server is working fine and has the status code "OK" i.e.

[image]

Returntype of my API is **IRestResponse**.

So, i assume there is some issue at angular side but, i am unable to figure out the issue. Can someone please help me in fixing the code.

Comment: Have u testing in postman first ? and is it a get request ?

Comment: yes, tested it postman. Yes, it is a get request @Madpop

Comment: This really looks like a server side issue. Can you expand the "error" in the error message? That might contian information that will help you find the error.

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually the issue was with returned response. I was returning whole response from API to server as it is but, i have to re-generate the file and return it. This solved my issue.